# return empty object while marshel python object

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, marshalling

i am trying to read data from a table with FK relation and return to UI by using Flask framework in python. it returns empty set for chiled table
Code, which I am working on

```
class User(Base,object):
    __tablename__ = "user_account"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
    full_name: Mapped[Optional[str]]
    
    address: Mapped[List["Address"]] = relationship(back_populates= "user" , cascade="all, delete-orphan")
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"User(id={self.id!r}, name={self.name!r}, full_name={self.full_name!r})"
  

class Address(Base,object):
    __tablename__= "address"
    
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    email_address: Mapped[str]
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user_account.id"))
    user: Mapped["User"]= relationship(back_populates="address")
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
       return f"Address(id={self.id!r}, email_address={self.email_address!r})"
   
user_fields = {
    "id": fields.Integer,
    "name": fields.String,
    "full_name": fields.String,
    "address": {
    "id": fields.Integer,
    "email_address": fields.String,
    }
}

    
    session = Session(engine)
    
    stmt = select(User).where(User.name.in_(["Nuh"]))
           
    for user in session.scalars(stmt):
        print(marshal(user,user_fields) )
```

{
"address": {
"email_address": null,
"id": 1
},
"full_name": "Nuh Panthodi",
"id": 1,
"name": "Nuh"
}

any help is apprciated